# Outlook New Mail Window opened from C# seems to have focus but my app still has it

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop, office-automation

I'm having a problem that I've been trying to solve for days now, but without luck!

On my Windows Forms Application I have a grid. One column contains an email address. When the user double clicks this column, I want to open a new E-Mail Window via Outlook automation. This window should have the focus and allow the user to type immediately.

Everything works fine, when:

- I'm running my app from Visual Studio.
- Or my app has the focus.

However, when I run my .exe **and** outlook has the focus when I double click the column, the following happens:

- The new Mail window opens as expected
- The cursor blinks in the new mail window (as expected)
- when the user starts typing, the cursor still blinks in outlook **but** the typed text appears in the grid of my application, not in outlook.

I was able to reproduce the problem with a simple form that has a textbox on it.

I use the following code:

```
private void textBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
 OpenOutlookMail(textBox1.Text);
}

private void OpenOutlookMail(string to)
{
  MailItem item = OutlookApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem) as MailItem;
  item.To = to;
  item.Subject = string.Empty;
  item.Body = string.Empty;

  item.Display();
}

protected Application OutlookApp
{
    get
    {
        if (mOutlookApp == null)
        {
            mOutlookApp = new Application();

        }
        return mOutlookApp;
     }
  }
```

What i already tried was to

- Activate my current form via this.Activate() before the call to OpenOutlookMail
- Activate the MailItem Inspector Object
- Activate the ActiveWindow and ActiveExplorer of Outlook via Automation
- Using AutoIt as explained here [Similar Problem with MS Word on the MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/worddev/thread/58b5f15c-a637-4d96-b7b7-05378107eb17)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote about focusing a background window some time ago:

http://blog.sebastianbrand.com/2010/02/activate-form-in-background.html

```
private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // mainform.BringToFront(); // doesn't work
  BeginInvoke(new VoidHandler(OtherFormToFront));
}

delegate void VoidHandler();

private void OtherFormToFront()
{
  mainform.BringToFront(); // works
}
```

If you do have an handle of the bad window, give that a try.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try when I'm back in the office at the end of this week

Comment: Your link to your [blog is dead](http://blog.sebastianbrand.com/2010/02/activate-form-in-background.html), at least now. Did u move it?

Comment: I killed the blog, but the content is just the same as here ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...) with some low priority in your textBox1_MouseDoubleClick(...) method to call OpenOutlookMail(). It often helps to workaround focus management issues like this one.

Comment: I'll give this a try when I'm back at my clients office in two weeks. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to reproduce the problem with your code.  I've used Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook version 14.0.0.0 and in every tests i've done the mail window get the focus.

As you state,

> Everything works fine, when:
>    •I'm running my app from Visual Studio.
>    •**Or my app has the focus.**

Maybe trying to focus your form and/or making your application sleep before opening the mail window would work

```
private void textBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.Focus();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    OpenOutlookMail(textBox1.Text);
}
```

Interops often have weird behaviors. :s

Comment: Hi Guish, thanks for your response. I tried both, Focus and Sleep as well as Application.DoEvents, but nothing helps

Comment: Try to execute your app "as admin".